# Ray and flow conflict

Tags: flow-project

ERROR: Cannot install flow==0.5.0.dev0 and ray==0.8.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
flow 0.5.0.dev0 depends on redis~=2.10.6
ray 0.8.0 depends on redis>=3.3.2

To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

enter image description here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmm1k.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get this to go through, you can just follow the instructions. I removed the version number from 'redis' in requirements.txt (in the flow repository, i.e., /path/to/flow), such that that line just reads:
"redis"
after this it does go through.

I am getting stuck myself with some later steps, so not sure if the higher redis will cause issues.

(provided binaries don't work for me on debian 10, and  documentation, https://flow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flow_setup.html,  says "Flow is not currently compatible with the most up-to-date version of SUMO." not sure what version of SUMO is compatible...?)